# 502 Bad Gateway Gateway with Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, service, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster with 2 nodes. I have deployed MySQL with 3 Pods, a master one for writing and 2 workers for reading.
I have a simple nodejs application which connects and reads from MySQL DB called emails_db.
I created the database simply by entering the master MySQL pod and the nodejs applications should read from the DB.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  serviceName: mysql
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init-mysql
        image: mysql:5.7
        command:
        - bash
        - "-c"
        - |
          set -ex
          # Generate mysql server-id from pod ordinal index.
          [[ `hostname` =~ -([0-9]+)$ ]] || exit 1
          ordinal=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
          echo [mysqld] > /mnt/conf.d/server-id.cnf
          # Add an offset to avoid reserved server-id=0 value.
          echo server-id=$((100 + $ordinal)) >> /mnt/conf.d/server-id.cnf
          # Copy appropriate conf.d files from config-map to emptyDir.
          if [[ $ordinal -eq 0 ]]; then
            cp /mnt/config-map/primary.cnf /mnt/conf.d/
          else
            cp /mnt/config-map/replica.cnf /mnt/conf.d/
          fi          
        volumeMounts:
        - name: conf
          mountPath: /mnt/conf.d
        - name: config-map
          mountPath: /mnt/config-map
      - name: clone-mysql
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/xtrabackup:1.0
        command:
        - bash
        - "-c"
        - |
          set -ex
          # Skip the clone if data already exists.
          [[ -d /var/lib/mysql/mysql ]] && exit 0
          # Skip the clone on primary (ordinal index 0).
          [[ `hostname` =~ -([0-9]+)$ ]] || exit 1
          ordinal=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
          [[ $ordinal -eq 0 ]] && exit 0
          # Clone data from previous peer.
          ncat --recv-only mysql-$(($ordinal-1)).mysql 3307 | xbstream -x -C /var/lib/mysql
          # Prepare the backup.
          xtrabackup --prepare --target-dir=/var/lib/mysql          
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
          subPath: mysql
        - name: conf
          mountPath: /etc/mysql/conf.d
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql:5.7
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
          value: "1"
        ports:
        - name: mysql
          containerPort: 3306
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
          subPath: mysql
        - name: conf
          mountPath: /etc/mysql/conf.d
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 1Gi
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command: ["mysqladmin", "ping"]
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            # Check we can execute queries over TCP (skip-networking is off).
            command: ["mysql", "-h", "127.0.0.1", "-e", "SELECT 1"]
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 2
          timeoutSeconds: 1
      - name: xtrabackup
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/xtrabackup:1.0
        ports:
        - name: xtrabackup
          containerPort: 3307
        command:
        - bash
        - "-c"
        - |
          set -ex
          cd /var/lib/mysql

          # Determine binlog position of cloned data, if any.
          if [[ -f xtrabackup_slave_info && "x$(<xtrabackup_slave_info)" != "x" ]]; then
            # XtraBackup already generated a partial "CHANGE MASTER TO" query
            # because we're cloning from an existing replica. (Need to remove the tailing semicolon!)
            cat xtrabackup_slave_info | sed -E 's/;$//g' > change_master_to.sql.in
            # Ignore xtrabackup_binlog_info in this case (it's useless).
            rm -f xtrabackup_slave_info xtrabackup_binlog_info
          elif [[ -f xtrabackup_binlog_info ]]; then
            # We're cloning directly from primary. Parse binlog position.
            [[ `cat xtrabackup_binlog_info` =~ ^(.*?)[[:space:]]+(.*?)$ ]] || exit 1
            rm -f xtrabackup_binlog_info xtrabackup_slave_info
            echo "CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='${BASH_REMATCH[1]}',\
                  MASTER_LOG_POS=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" > change_master_to.sql.in
          fi

          # Check if we need to complete a clone by starting replication.
          if [[ -f change_master_to.sql.in ]]; then
            echo "Waiting for mysqld to be ready (accepting connections)"
            until mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -e "SELECT 1"; do sleep 1; done

            echo "Initializing replication from clone position"
            mysql -h 127.0.0.1 \
                  -e "$(<change_master_to.sql.in), \
                          MASTER_HOST='mysql-0.mysql', \
                          MASTER_USER='root', \
                          MASTER_PASSWORD='', \
                          MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY=10; \
                        START SLAVE;" || exit 1
            # In case of container restart, attempt this at-most-once.
            mv change_master_to.sql.in change_master_to.sql.orig
          fi

          # Start a server to send backups when requested by peers.
          exec ncat --listen --keep-open --send-only --max-conns=1 3307 -c \
            "xtrabackup --backup --slave-info --stream=xbstream --host=127.0.0.1 --user=root"          
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
          subPath: mysql
        - name: conf
          mountPath: /etc/mysql/conf.d
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
      volumes:
      - name: conf
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: config-map
        configMap:
          name: mysql
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
    spec:
      accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
```

Nodejs Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nodejs
  name: nodejs-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nodejs
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 5000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3306
```

Nodejs Deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nodejs
  labels:
    app: nodejs
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nodejs
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nodejs
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nodejs
        image: 199266549/my-nodeapi:PortLatest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000 
        env:
        - name: db-url
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:  
              name: myconfig
              key: db-url 
        - name: DB_NAME
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:  
              name: myconfig
              key: DB_NAME
        - name: DB_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:  
              name: mysecret
              key: DB_USER
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:  
              name: mysecret
              key: DB_PASSWORD
```

Ingress looks like this:

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mysql-ingress
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mysql.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /read
        backend:
          serviceName: mysql-read
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /write
        backend:
          serviceName: mysql
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: nodejs-service
          servicePort: 5000
```

target port is 3306  which is the port exposed by MySql.
While nodejs application exposes port 5000.

I tried the following curl command

```
curl -v -Hhost:mysql.com http://abccc302f198147aca906e71c710c661-29001ea7d40ff165.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
```

[image: curl command output]

I checked the ingress backend. The service of interest is the one given with path `/`

[image]

Any idea what is missing when trying to connect the nodjs service to MySql Pods?
Is this problematic?

```
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
```

Comment: Hello Sara, are you following some tutorial/guide to create a Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: Hello Mozello, 
For creating the cluster, it is a simple eksctl command, 
yes, for MySql I was following:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/

for Creating the nodejs deployment I followed this video and tried to get the hang of that, at this time stamp 1:16:16 - Demo Project: MongoDB and MongoExpress
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X48VuDVv0do 
The main difference is that, in the demo she is using NodePort, while in my case I am exposing the cluster using nginx load balancer.

Comment: Ok, first of all ingress should expose only your nodejs-service. Then you should point your nodejs deployment to mysql service (db-url). Also, correct nodejs service targetPort: to 5000. Please let me know the results.

Comment: To the OP: Please post your updates if you were able to solve this issue. This might actually help someone.